# Pass TextInput value to imported component

Tags: react-native, state, react-navigation

i am developing the mobile app in react native. i am new to react native so i am stuck at 1 point.

The issue is i have navigation file in which stack navigator wrapped in tab navigator.

i have a custom header with the drawer menu open button and search bar.

i have a separate component for search view. which is showing and hiding on my home page on the base of focusing on search bar.

Now the question in that on my home page when i click search bar the search component showing there, and what i need is to get the value of that search bar in my search component.

May be its little bit confusing please feel free to ask me anything.

i am going to attack images and my code as well.

> my navigation js looks like this.

```
import Search from '../Search/search';
```

> StackNavigator

```
const SearchBarI = (props) => {
return (
    (<View style={searchSection}>
        <TextInput style={searchBarInput} placeholder="Search" ref={input => { this.searchInput = input }}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)} />
        <Icon style={searchIcon} name="ios-search" size={20} color="#000" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={closeIconBtn} onPress={() => ClearText()}>
            <Icon style={closeIcon} name="ios-close" size={20} color="#000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>)
)
}
const feedStackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
feed: {
    screen: Feed,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
        return {

            headerTitle: <SearchBarI/>,
            headerStyle: headerStyle,
            headerRight: (
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ paddingRight: 10 }} onPress={(params.ClearSearch)}>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Cancel</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),

            headerLeft: <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation} />,


        }
    }
},
})
```

> ```
> And include in tab navigator and export it.
> ```

```
const appTabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
Feed: feedStackNavigation,
})


export default appTabNavigation;
```

what i need when onChangeText in my search bar i want to pass that value in my search component and need to change the state and other functionality there.

> Home Page Screenshot.

[image]

> After clicking on the search bar screenshot.

[image]

> after typing in search bar i got an alert which is the function inside
>   the navigation file.

[image]

Hope it will give you the clear look. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would work but i used some approach for this before, i needed intercommunication between 2 components in the same page and it was a nightmare. Now i don't use the header of react navigation because i have a custom header 7u7. But, you can try this.

First. Don't define  headerTitle in the navigationOptions of the stack. Instead, define it in the screen `Feed`.

So per example, in your screen feed you need to add  a static navigationoptions, and also send a callback as a prop to the headertitle

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {....}


  static navigationOptions = { //here is the navoptions
  headerTitle: <SearchBarI callback={this.handlecallback}/>  //here is the callback that we are sending
  };   


  handlecallback =(props)=>{ //here is the handler , it NEEDS to be a fat arrow function [that's how mafia works]
      alert(props)
       //do whatever you want in that page
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

and in your searchbar textinput

```
<TextInput style={searchBarInput} placeholder="Search" ref={input => { this.searchInput = input }}
            onChangeText={(text) => props.callback(text)} />
```

Comment: Thanks ValdaXD, gives me the right direction and your examples works for me.
Bundle of Thanks again.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of are hooks , in the future react native could have state's being shared between components wich is AWESOME. They are in development but should arrive in RN 0.59 / 0.60 7u7